# SQL Creating new variables

Tags: sql, sas

I am fairly inexperienced with SQL, but am working to try to condense my code into one query so that it is more efficient.  Below is a simplified example of a much more complex problem I have.  I am having problems with the syntax of creating the summary groups and variables.  In my case, the data are housed in several different table, but the joins are not a problem for me so I have only created one table here.

This is the data I have:

```
Name Class Wk Score ExCred X
Joe    A   1   35    ?     3
Hal    A   1   50    5     4
Sal    A   1   45    ?     3
Kim    B   1   30    5     6
Cal    B   1   40    ?     6
Joe    A   2   50    ?     2
Hal    A   2   40    ?     3
Sal    A   2   40    ?     4
Kim    B   2   40    5     5
Cal    B   2   40    ?     4
```

The table I am trying to create will look like this:

```
Class  Wk  Avg_Score  Sum_X
A      1      45        10
B      1      37.5      12
A      2      43.3      9
B      2      42.5      9
```

So, the data are summarized by class and week.  The avg_score is the average of the sum and 'score' and 'ExCred' for each student. Sum_X is simply the sum of X for each class.

I have had success with this in SAS SQL by using multiple proc means statements, but this is clunky and seems to take a really long time.  There has to be a more elegant way to do this.  I know it probably involves the group by statement..... Help?

Thanks.  Pyll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no particular reason not to use `proc means` here.  It should be significantly faster than `proc sql` on datasets of substantial size.

```
proc means data=have;
class class wk;
types class*wk;
var score x;
output out=want mean(score)= sum(x)=;
run;
```

Just preprocess the data to include ExCred into the Score variable; if execution time is an issue use a view to do so.

If you did want to do it in sql, you would indeed use a group by.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
   select class, wk, mean(score+ex_cred), sum(x)
    from have
    group by class, wk;
quit;
```

Comment: Since my data were in multiple tables, I had to use joins to create a table such as the one above BEFORE using proc means, then actually join more stuff in after that.  It was a mess.  So, now I am trying to do it in SQL (not SAS SQL).  The code above is not handling the missing values as zeroes, which is what I want.

Comment: I think I got it sorted with a 'zeroifnull' function.